# How to compare the Firebase retrieved value with a string?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Is there a way I can store the value retrieved from the Firebase to be stored in a String Variable?
Here is my code retrieving the Value of "rface":

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    rface = dataSnapshot.child("face").getValue(String.class);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
```

And I want to implement and if condition:

```
if (rface=="0") {
    do this
}
```

The rface contains a string value in my Firebase Database.
When I try to use this If condition Android Studio says:

> Operator "==" can not be applied to 'java.util.Objects','java.lang.String'

Comment: Use `if (rface.equals("0")) ...` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: It shows 'equals()' between objects of inconvertible types 'String' and 'Object'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast your object to a String like this:

```
rface = (String)dataSnapshot.child("face").getValue();
```

and then compare with `equals()`;